# Windows 10 COM crash under loader lock

Tags: c++, windows, core-audio

I stumbled across a Windows 10 crash that's probably new since the Windows 10 update to 2004.

The problem is a crash in ntdll when COM is starting. COM is needed to use Core Audio.

Code which triggers it:

```
    IMMDeviceEnumerator* enumerator = nullptr;
    CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_MULTITHREADED); // Also with STA
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance( CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator, 0,  CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator,
 (void**)&enumerator);
```

Popup:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFE7846D3D1 (ntdll.dll) in MicTest.exe:
> A LIST_ENTRY has been corrupted (i.e. double remove).

Callstack:

```
ntdll.dll!LdrpInsertDataTableEntry()    
ntdll.dll!LdrpMapDllWithSectionHandle() 
ntdll.dll!LdrpMapDllNtFileName()    
ntdll.dll!LdrpMapDllFullPath()  
ntdll.dll!LdrpProcessWork() 
ntdll.dll!LdrpLoadDllInternal() 
ntdll.dll!LdrpLoadForwardedDll()    
ntdll.dll!LdrpGetDelayloadExportDll()   
ntdll.dll!LdrpHandleProtectedDelayload()    
ntdll.dll!LdrResolveDelayLoadedAPI()    
combase.dll!00007ffe769ab1c2()  
combase.dll!00007ffe769c56fd()  
combase.dll!00007ffe769b3b27()  
ntdll.dll!RtlRunOnceExecuteOnce()   
KernelBase.dll!InitOnceExecuteOnce()    
combase.dll!00007ffe7696c11f()  
combase.dll!00007ffe7696baf8()  
combase.dll!00007ffe7696b9e6()  
combase.dll!00007ffe76907df2()  
combase.dll!00007ffe76906fce()  
combase.dll!00007ffe76907928()  
combase.dll!00007ffe76907718()  
MicTest.exe!Microphone::Microphone() Line 23    C++
[External Code] 
MicTest.exe!main(int argc, char * * argv) Line 67   C++
```

It's not 100% reproducible there, sometimes the crash is a few lines later in `IAudioClient::Initialize` when ntdll crashes under loader lock in

```
>   ntdll.dll!LdrpInitializeThread()    
    ntdll.dll!_LdrpInitialize() 
    ntdll.dll!LdrpInitialize()  
    ntdll.dll!LdrInitializeThunk()
```

This happens in one of the new Windows 10 threadpool threads that Windows itself uses to load a DLL. The offending code shows up as `AudioSes.dll!CAudioClient::CreateRemoteStream` (Note: AudioSes.dll is Core Audio, symbols per the Microsoft Symbol Server.)

Is this a known problem? Is there a workaround?

For completeness, complete code:

```
Microphone::Microphone() 
    
{
    IMMDeviceEnumerator* enumerator = nullptr;
    CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_MULTITHREADED); // crash near here
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance( CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator, 0,  CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator, (void**)&enumerator);
    if (!enumerator) throw std::system_error(hr, std::system_category());
    IMMDevice* device = nullptr;
    hr = enumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eCapture, eConsole, &device);
    enumerator->Release();
    if (!device) throw std::system_error(hr, std::system_category());
    hr = device->Activate(IID_IAudioClient, CLSCTX_ALL, NULL, (void**)&client);
    device->Release();
    if (!client) throw std::system_error(hr, std::system_category());

    WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE *pwfx = nullptr;
    hr = client->GetMixFormat(reinterpret_cast<WAVEFORMATEX**>(&pwfx));
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && pwfx)
    {
        this->span.sampleRate = pwfx->Format.nSamplesPerSec;
        this->blockAlign = pwfx->Format.nBlockAlign;
        // In general, this is NOT pwfx->wBitsPerSample;
        if (pwfx->SubFormat == KSDATAFORMAT_SUBTYPE_IEEE_FLOAT)
        {
            this->format = fmt_FP32;
        }
        else if (pwfx->SubFormat == KSDATAFORMAT_SUBTYPE_PCM)
        {
            this->format = fmt_PCM;
        }
        else
        {
            // Can't deal with that format, and Core Audio ought to support FP32.
            pwfx->SubFormat = KSDATAFORMAT_SUBTYPE_IEEE_FLOAT;
            this->format = fmt_FP32;
        }
    }
    // or crash here
    hr = client->Initialize(AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_SHARED, 0, 1000000, 0, &pwfx->Format, NULL);
    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        throw std::system_error(hr, std::system_category());
    }
    CoTaskMemFree(pwfx);

    // Start capture
    hr = client->GetService( IID_IAudioCaptureClient, (void**)&capture);
    client->Start();
```

Comment: crash inside `CoInitializeEx` or `CoCreateInstance( CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator` ? you have no correct symbols for *combase.dll*. in any case look as system bug.. if you not already corrupt heap/memory of process in another place. what concrete module is loaded during crash ? all this of course need look under debugger

Comment: @RbMm: It's a bit tricky to debug as there seems to be a race condition with the crash in the threadpool thread. The concrete module appears to be AudioSes.DLL, which is a Core Audio DLL that was updated as part of the W10 2004 release.

Comment: possible disable parallel loader, so all will be in single thread. but i think task not in this. debug is possible. are you at very begin from program call `Microphone::Microphone()` and crash inside `CoCreateInstance( CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator ` ? so this can be stable reproduced ?

Comment: @RbMm: TBH I'm now seeing the second type of crash in `IAudioClient::Initialize`. While searching I did find out that the 2004 update has known issues with Realtek audio, and the particular device is in fact a laptop microphone connected to a Realtek audio chip. So this is probably not the fault of the code above.

Comment: for say exactly what happens need deep look under debugger

Answer (score 0):

As RbMm pointed out, this requires looking at the assembly. It turns out that Windows 10 2004 corrupts its `PEB_LDR_DATA` data structure. This is a per-process structure which contains important data. In particular, `LdrpInitializeThread` uses `PEB_LDR_DATA::InLoadOrderModuleList` directly after acquiring the Loader Lock. This can be a null pointer for unclear reasons.

Since this happens in a Windows-created thread in the default threadpool, it's unrelated to and unsynchronized with user code. The exact point of crash can vary - the damage to the `PEB_LDR_DATA` structure appears to be more extensive.

## Workaround

While this is not a solution for the `CoInitializeEx` crash, it appears that the second crash due to `PEB_LDR_DATA::InLoadOrderModuleList` corruption can be avoided with minor changes:

- Don't set a buffer size, but let Windows determine one and roll with that:

```
    hr = client->Initialize(AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_SHARED, 0, 0, 0, &pwfx->Format, NULL);
    UINT32 bufSize = 0;
    hr = client->GetBufferSize(&bufSize);
```

- Determine when to call `GetBuffer`

```
    auto samplePollRatio = pwfx->Format.nSamplesPerSec / 2666;
    auto nextPoll = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + 
    std::chrono::milliseconds(bufSize / samplePollRatio);
```

- And wait for it

```
    std::this_thread::sleep_until(nextPoll);
    auto hr = capture->GetBuffer(&buf, &samples, &flags, nullptr, nullptr);
```

This is a reasonable pattern anyway. The [MSDN example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/capturing-a-stream) also has a `Sleep` call, but `sleep_until` is more robust against variable delays in processing. (E.g. on the first call you may have some more delay when opening a WAV file to save the results etc). But by delaying the first sample acquisition you bypass an apparent race condition in Windows 10.

Comment: i however think this is very specific and narrow error, but without view concrete case under debugger can not say more based on your info

Comment: you callstack look like [this](https://i.imgur.com/JUPqwAU.png) (you have no symbols for *combase.dll*). this is during call to `GetCurrentPackageId` from *kernel.appcore.dll*. if system crash in this point the process memory already corrupted by some reason (really `CoInitializeEx` is permanently called in system and if here will be bug, even sometime/random - all system will be very visible unstable). so i guesss something in your concrete system or process. i personally can not reproduce this even on 2004

Comment: @RbMm: I might have found a cause for the memory corruption. I spotted that `sizeof(Microphone)` was not consistent in the Visual Studio debugger - the COM-specific stuff was inside a `#ifdef WIN32` section, but this wasn't defined where `std::make_unique<Microphone>` was instantiated. (or at least not for the winning instantiation). App Verifier helped to pinpoint it by making the crash more reproducible.