# Unable to Debug C++ Application in VS 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I have a C++ project that I am able to build and run as an exe just fine.

However, when I try to debug the project in Visual Studio 2019 I get the following error:

**"Unhandled exception at 0x75D7C66B (shell32.dll) in MyApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004"**

It also says: "**Source Not Available: Source information is missing from the debug information for this module"**

I don't understand this error. **I have set breakpoints right at the beginning of the main()** function but it never gets to these breakpoints so I don't know what causes the exception.

I have googled this for quite sometime but haven't found any similar problems.

I hope someone can help. Let me know if you need further details.

Edit: here is the call stack:

> shell32.dll!CShellFolderViewOC::GetConnMap(int *)   Unknown
> shell32.dll!`dynamic initializer for 'ATL::IConnectionPointContainerImpl::pConnMap''()  Unknown
> ucrtbase.dll!__initterm()   Unknown
> shell32.dll!dllmain_crt_process_attach()    Unknown
> shell32.dll!dllmain_crt_dispatch()  Unknown
> shell32.dll!dllmain_dispatch()  Unknown
> shell32.dll!__DllMainCRTStartup@12()    Unknown
> ntdll.dll!_LdrxCallInitRoutine@16() Unknown
> ntdll.dll!LdrpCallInitRoutine() Unknown
> ntdll.dll!LdrpInitializeNode()  Unknown
> ntdll.dll!LdrpInitializeGraphRecurse()  Unknown
> ntdll.dll!LdrpInitializeGraphRecurse()  Unknown
> ntdll.dll!LdrpPrepareModuleForExecution()   Unknown
> ntdll.dll!LdrpLoadDllInternal() Unknown
> ntdll.dll!LdrLoadDll()  Unknown
> 01240307()  Unknown
> [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing]  Unknown
> ntdll.dll!_KiUserApcDispatcher@16() Unknown
> ntdll.dll!LdrInitializeThunk()  Unknown

Comment: Globals are initialised before `main` is called so problems initialised them could be the cause.  However without a [mcve] this is just a guess.

Comment: Look at the call stack and locate your faulty module from there.  You can also set breakpoints on global variable definitions and in any of your constructors you suspect may be faulty.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy it sounds worse. If it could't locate source, that may mean that call stack is killed post-mortem `[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing] `. That's a hell to debug. If project have a version control, it's time for binary search of issue.

Comment: But how come that it works fine when I build the exe file but not when I debug?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie  That's why putting breakpoints in constructors or on global scope variable definitions may and will help.  Stopping execution before main() and stepping from there WILL in any case help in finding the error.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy No, it didn't. (See my answer) The exception was thrown while loading the symbols before any of my code was executed. So putting breakpoints in global declarations did not help.

Comment: @ST11280709  I'm glad you found your bug.  But sometimes it helps, that's all I said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.

In Visual Studio under:

Options -> Debugging -> General

I **disabled** the option: "Load debug symbols in external process (Native only)"

I still don't really understand **why** this fixed the problem. If someone could explain I would be grateful.

Comment: You either have outdated symbols (version not compatible with OS version) or something is broken. There also was issue with out-of-process debugging crash with V2019, which was fixed by now, afaik. It might be OS issues similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63342660/windows-10-com-crash-under-loader-lock